# Как сделать выравнивание контейнеров по ширине?

Tags: css3, xhtml, html, css

Есть меню, реализованное в виде списка, элементами списка являются ссылки. Необходимо получить горизонтальную полосу, динамически расширяющуюся в зависимости от размеров окна. 
text-align:justify работает только с обычным текстом, с контейнерами(span,a)  эффекта нет.

Comment: А при чем тут `text-align`, если речь идет не о тексте??? О_о

Comment: Приведите проблемный код.

Comment: Вот пример:
html:  
<ul>  
     <li><a href="#">ссылочка 1</a></li>  
     <li><a href="#">еще какая-то ссылочка</a></li>  
     <li><a href="#">другая ссылочка</a></li>  
     <li><a href="#">и последняя</a></li>  
</ul>  
css:  
ul {width: 100%; 
list-style-type: none; }
li { 
   float: left; 
   clear: none; 
}

Comment: Это вам  в один ряд надо ставить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще вы фигней занимаетесь. Но подскажу - вам нужно хакать, примерно так

```
ul { display: block; list-style: none; text-align: justify; height: 30px; overflow: hidden; }
li { display: inline; line-height: 30px; padding: 0px 10px; /*минимальный отступ*/ }
```

и добавлять 1 li шириной заведомо больше меню *без переноса*

```
<ul>
  <li>menu1</li>
  <li>menu2</li>
  <li>menu3</li>
  <li>menu4</li>
  <li>menu5</li>
  <li><img src="любая-картинка.jpg" width="800"></li>
</ul>
```

Примерно так. То есть, текстовые элементы растягиваются ровно на все доступное пространство с мин. отступом 10px. Последний элемент нужен для того, чтобы 100% получилось 2 строки в итоге.

Comment: вот это работает как надо, хотя я и не понял суть этого последнего элемента.. :)

Comment: `justify` для одной строки работает как `left`, а если предложение выходит за край - слова растягиваются на всю строку, а 2 строчка опять работает как `left`.

Comment: так вот в чем проблема была) вот этой тонкости насчет 2 строк не знал, спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Делаете функцию примерно такую:

```
function getThisWindowWidth() {
    return screen.availWidth;
}
```

Она возвращает ширину экрана. На всякий случай, вот для высоты:

```
function getThisWindowHeight() {
    return screen.availHeight - 90;
}
```

Вот.
P.S. Но если будете менять ширину окна мышкой, то не подействует. Надо тогда как-то выстебнуться для слежением за изменением размеров окна.

UPD1:
Можно попробовать в CSS установить `width: 100%`

*UPD2*:
Ах ё! Сделайте в качестве примера так:

```
li {
    width: 30%;
    background: #00FF00;
}
```

И все элементы будут 30% от ширины окна.
Или, если касаться именно вашего примера, то так:

```
ul { } 
li { 
    width: 100%; 
    float: left; 
    clear: none; 
    list-style-type: none; 
}
```

*UPD3*:
Вот

```
li {
    padding-right: 20px;
    float: left;
    clear: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: #00FF00;
}
```

Фоновый цвет поставил для того, чтобы видеть точно, что получилось.

Comment: width: 30% не вариант. вы сами пробовали это? ну хорошо, задаем размер контейнеров, текст то контейнерах тоже везде раздной ширины, а значит остаток где-то будет заполнен пустотой. как результат - не равномерность.

Comment: Так что же в конце-то концов вам надо? Сформулируйте точно вопрос, от начала и до конца.

Comment: Исправил в первом посте. Мне важно расстояние между видимой частью этих элементов li. т.е между их текстовыми составляющими.

Comment: пример - bitmemory.ru Только там жестко все фиксированно, ничего не растягивается. Выглядеть должно так же, но при этом быть резиновым :)

Comment: Это вы про верхнее меню? Тогда ответ верен.  
Вот только там не используют в качестве выравнивания на одну строку свойство `float: left; `